# HTML width messed up by border

Tags: html, css

HTML/CSS novice here.

Trying to put into practice what I've learned on Codeacademy and I'm stuck with an issue where my header which is set to width:100% ends up going off the page. I believe it is because of the border as when I set it to 1px instead of 10px it very nearly fits onto the page.

I've attached a couple of screenshots and my code, I'm sure there's a really easy solution to this and whilst I'm not massively fussed whether I have a border or not I need to understand why this is happening.

Thanks in advance.

```
#header {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
background-color: white;
border: 10px solid black;
font-size: 80px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Helvetica, Ariel, Sans;
```

}

```
.left {
height:400px;
width:100px;
background-color:white;
border:10px solid black;
float:left;
```

}

```
.right {
height: 400px;
width: 100px;
background-color: white;
border: 10px solid black;
float: right;
```

}

Image: http://postimg.org/image/b0vnu2okf/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: generally, borders count towards sizing calculations. a 1px border on a 100% box is (100% + 2px) wide, actually

Comment: Are you wanting this to be responsive? What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you are, just add a max-width: 100% to your img and your header will stay on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a border increases the element's width past 100%.

You can play with the box model, as others have suggested, using `box-sizing`.

However, in this case, I suggest removing `width:100%`.
The `<div>` will span the entire width of the page by default.

You can also safely remove `margin:auto`.

```
div#header {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 10px solid black;
    font-size: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica, Ariel, Sans;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/93EPg/

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to calculate the width and height of the box including the paddings and borders.

Also, you could use `* { box-sizing: border-box }` on everything. as suggested by **[Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)**.

Comment: This is the best model. I doubt it matters for you OP, but IE7 and below won't support this. But to hell with them! ;)